# How can i read text file and load data to an array?

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a .txt file that follows the next format:

```
00:00.300      ID:4        zzzzzzzzzzz                
00:02.155      ID:4        aaaaaaaaaaaaa        
00:04.662      ID:4        dsadasd  
**00:32.283**      ID:4        level **790**  
00:32.155      ID:4        Sfghgfs  
00:32.200      ID:4        Tsdfsdfdfsff  
**00:32.205**      ID:4        level **640**  
00:32.206      ID:4        Sadssd  
00:32.208      ID:4        asdasgsfgsgsagsa  
00:32.210      ID:4        adasgx  
00:32.212      ID:4        Masddasdas.  
**01:40:40.698**   ID:4        level **500**
```

So, I want to scan the file and extract the time to an array whenever appears in the line "level XXX". 
After this, i want to read the correspondent level and save in another array to draw a graphic with both.

I tried the functions: `textscan` and `strfind` but it doesn't work.
Can you guys help me?

Comment: Please show us your attempt and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, It's always ' level ' with a space before and after.

Comment: At this moment i only know how to get the number of the lines where appear "level". I can not extract the information after this

Comment: then show the code you have already, and explain the part which work and the part which doesn't please.

Comment: sure, i want something like this:
Output1=[00:32.283; 00:32.205; 01:40:40.698];
Output2=[790; 640; 500];

Comment: Are the `*` actually there in the text or did you insert them just to highlight that bit of text?

Comment: The ** weren't in the original. I think he added that to highlight - but the bold text was better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
raw = fileread('mytext.txt');
tokens = regexp(raw,'((?:\d{2}:)?\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})[^\n]+level[^\d]+(\d{3})','tokens');
tokens = [tokens{:}];
timestamps = tokens(1:2:end);
levels = tokens(2:2:end);
```

Inspect outputs:

```
>> timestamps

timestamps =

  1×3 cell array

    {'00:32.283'}    {'00:32.205'}    {'01:40:40.698'}

>> levels

levels =

  1×3 cell array

    {'790'}    {'640'}    {'500'}
```

You can see how the regex works [here](https://regex101.com/r/VDiEFy/1).

Answer (score 0):

This just displays the value for the time_stamp and the level. Feel free to pass them to whatever you want after that.

```
ff = fopen('filename.txt');

while ~feof(ff)
    A = fgetl(ff);
    if contains(A,'level')
    time_stamp = sscanf(A,'%s ID:4 break_here') % the 'break_here' string is intended to not match the text in the file
    level = sscanf(A,strcat(time_stamp,' ID:4 level %f'))
    end
end
fclose(ff);
```